# Kinetic Energy of a rotating cone

Tags: calculus, integration

We have a regular circular cone of base radius R, height H and equally distributed mass M that rotates on its axis with a circular velocity $\omega$.

How do we calculate it's energy via integration? Having a hard time expressing it. I guess I should divide the cone in small concentric tubes which have constant speed ... ?

Comment: Is the "cone" a right circular cone? Is the axis of rotation the axis of the cone? Is the mass uniformly distributed in the cone? Are you looking only at the kinetic energy of the cone?

Comment: Find the moment of inertia $I$ of the cone about its axis of rotation, then the kinetic energy is $\frac 12 I\omega^2$ (assuming the axis is fixed)

Comment: Right Rory sorry, I edited.